# Отправка почты debian 7 VDS

Tags: debian, smtp

Пишу ресурс по массовой рассылке. Планируется отправлять большие количества. Сервис для наших клиентов. Для начала планируем **5 000 - 10 000** писем в день. Потянет ли это сервер (скрипт по крону, рассылающий из очереди, которая в базе. **100-300** за **1** раз). Можно ли реализовать через агента `sendmail` (я так понимаю, функция `mail()` реализует эту функциональность).

1. Как можно настроить сервер (**isp, ssh**)?
2. Будет ли это сильно загружать сервер?

Comment: 1. что именно вы подразумеваете под термином «агент sendmail»? 2. расшифруйте, пожалуйста, о какой именно «нагрузке» речь, и по каким критериям следует оценивать, «сильно» загружен сервер или «не сильно».

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sendmail.

Comment: понятно. да, конечно, можно. хотя я бы рекомендовал дефолтный debian-овский exim в качестве smtp-сервера. а по второму пункту ничего не можете добавить?

Comment: Я просто не знаю, как определить загруженность сервера при рассылке на большие мейл-базы. У меня на сервере стоят параллельно 2 игровых ресурса, которые так же требуют ресурсов сервера. А по поводу exim есть линки для настройки? Я так понимаю, это готовый smtp сервер. Мне уже советовали поднять свой. Как его правильно настроить и использовать?

Comment: какой ресурс у вас сейчас наиболее дефицитен? если это не сетевой трафик, то по поводу потребления ресурсов smtp-сервером, пожалуй, беспокоиться стоит в последнюю очередь.

Comment: Почитал немного про exim. Сначала думал, что это смтп сервер, но как понял, это утилита типа sendmail, которая указывает программу, через которую функция mail() будет отправлять почту. Верно? Чем хорош exim? У меня сейчас выбран sendmail.

Comment: exim, sendmail, postfix — это smtp-серверы, или (с точки зрения выполняемых функций) — mta — mail transfer agents (их ещё много  существует). помимо прочего, название sendmail используется как «каноническое имя» для используемого в системе mta, чтобы унифицировать обращения к нему. // например, команда `readlink -f /usr/sbin/sendmail` при установленном пакете exim4 вернёт что-нибудь вроде `/usr/sbin/exim4`, а при установленном postfix-е — что-нибудь вроде `/usr/sbin/sendmail.postfix`

Comment: Если это smtp серверы, зачем проводить аутентификацию через smtp.gmail.com ? Видел это на разных примерах. или я чего то не понимаю? Я думал, самый разумный вариант - поднять smtp сервер и через него осуществлять массовую рассылку. Чем дальше - тем меньше понимаю =)

Comment: я не знаю, откуда взялась аутентификация через другой сервер, но, конечно, любой smtp-сервер способен работать в режиме использования [*smarthost*-а](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smart_host). // массовые (читай — спамерские) рассылки — со своего smtp-сервера, работающего в полноценном режиме, требуют много не зависящих от самого smtp-сервера усилий/настроек/внимания (постоянного), так что иногда использование smarthost-а (или даже специализированного сервиса рассылки) может быть предпочтительней.

Comment: Позвольте нам [продолжить обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26836/discussion-between-alexander-barakin-and--).

Comment: О, Хорошая идея

Answer (score 1):

Для подобных рассылок необходимо использовать нечто вроде mailgun.

Если провайдер ограничивает количество smtp, то наверняка есть какие-либо ограничения.
Либо вас забанит провайдер либо почтовый сервер.

Answer (score 0):

> 5 000 - 10 000 писем в день

при таком мизерном количестве писем переживать по поводу производительности машины вряд ли имеет смысл. ну, разве что она выполняет какие-нибудь другие, действительно ресурсоёмкие задачи.

вот пропускная способность сетевого канала, через который сервер общается с внешним миром — может быть значительно более существенна. особенно учитывая нынешние аппетиты отправителей писем с много-мегабайтными вложениями.